# Mysql Inserting Or Updating one table column data to another table with Matching valus

Tags: php, mysql

Iam bit new to Mysql,  What is my question is, how to Update or Insert **Table_1** column data  to **Table_2**  column data with matching the relevant Id's from **Table_1**.

**For Eg.**

```
          Table_1                       Table_2                      

        rand  | cpn                   rand   |  cpn     
         1        4                     2        0
         2        7                     3        0
         3        2                     5        0
         4        1                     1        0
         5        7                     4        0
```

The above mentioned table are the current structure of the my tables, my output should be like this,

```
      Table_2

   rand   |  cpn     
     2        7
     3        2
     5        7
     1        4
     4        1
```

I want to match the ids from **table_1** and update in **table_2**, accordingly Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you can use joins in updates to achive the expected results:

```
update table2 t2 inner join table1 t1 on t2.rand=t1.rand
set t2.cpn=t1.cpn
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
update table2 t2 set cpn = (select cpn from table1 where rand = t2.rand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should `JOIN` the tables so you can use the values, like so:

```
UPDATE Table_2 t2 
LEFT JOIN Table_1 t1 on t2.rand = t1.rand
SET t2.cpn = t1.cpn;
```

Comment: thats not insert rows in Table_2

Comment: @BerndBuffen you cannot insert matching data, only update it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Noy, the query u suggested is executing but nothing is happening 0 rows affected :(

Comment: @Crysis there is a typo in the set statement, you should have spotted it. However, I would not use left join because that will overwrite non/matching values with nulls.

Comment: @BerndBuffen It inserts the non-matching records, but this was not the question.

Comment: @Shadow : Thats the Question: Iam bit new to Mysql, What is my question is, how to **Update or Insert** Table_1 column data to Table_2 column data with matching the relevant Id's from Table_1.

Comment: @BerndBuffen you, too. The OP was happy with the answer. Any more questions?

Comment: @shadow: but it works only if you have the same rows in both tables and he asked for insert and update

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. it INSERT OR UPDATE Records. You only must have a unique INDEX or PRIMARY KEY on rand.

```
INSERT INTO Table_2
 (SELECT * FROM Table_1 )
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cpn = VALUES(cpn);
```

**SAMPLE**

```
MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> CREATE TABLE `Table_1` (
    ->   `rand` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `cpn` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`rand`)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> INSERT INTO `Table_1` (`rand`, `cpn`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1, 4),
    -> (2, 7),
    -> (3, 2),
    -> (4, 1),
    -> (5, 7);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB []>
MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> CREATE TABLE `Table_2` (
    ->   `rand` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `cpn` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`rand`)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> INSERT INTO `Table_2` (`rand`, `cpn`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1, 0),
    -> (2, 0),
    -> (3, 0),
    -> (4, 0),
    -> (5, 0);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB []>
MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> SELECT * FROM Table_1;
+------+------+
| rand | cpn  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    4 |
|    2 |    7 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    4 |    1 |
|    5 |    7 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> SELECT * FROM Table_2;
+------+------+
| rand | cpn  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |
|    2 |    0 |
|    3 |    0 |
|    4 |    0 |
|    5 |    0 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> INSERT INTO Table_2
    ->  (SELECT * FROM Table_1 )
    ->  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cpn = VALUES(cpn);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 5  Warnings: 0

MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> SELECT * FROM Table_2;
+------+------+
| rand | cpn  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    4 |
|    2 |    7 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    4 |    1 |
|    5 |    7 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Comment: Do not Downvote. It work 100% good if you build everything correct. See my changed anwser !!!