# Insert from another table, and update if key exists, possible in one query?

Tags: mysql

MySQL:

I can insert data to one table from another, with this query:

```
INSERT INTO design (id_event,id_theme,color_main,color_bg)  
SELECT '123',
       '5',
       color_main,
       color_bg 
FROM theme 
WHERE id_theme='5'
```

and i can also update it, like this:

```
UPDATE design INNER JOIN theme ON design.id_theme=theme.id_theme
SET design.color_main=theme.color_main, design.color_bg=theme.color_bg
WHERE id_event='123'
```

Is it possible to combine this 2 queries into one, like this:

```
INSERT INTO design (id_event,id_theme,color_main,color_bg) 
SELECT '123','5',color_main,color_bg FROM theme WHERE id_theme='5'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_theme='5',color_main=???,color_bg=???
```

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: look at my answer : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503432/mysql-inserting-or-updating-one-table-column-data-to-another-table-with-matching/35503709#35503709](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503432/mysql-inserting-or-updating-one-table-column-data-to-another-table-with-matching/35503709#35503709)

Comment: but it updates only 1 value, if i use it in my case i'll have to make 3 or more SELECTs in my query... and also it not worked for me in MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
INSERT INTO design (id_event,id_theme,color_main,color_bg) 
SELECT '123','5',color_main,color_bg FROM theme WHERE id_theme='5'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 id_theme=VALUES(id_theme),
 color_main=VALUES(color_main),
 color_bg=VALUES(color_bg) ......;
```